# unable to see images or pull from registry

Tags: google-container-registry

I am unable to see images from the registry

1. gcloud auth login
2. from local machine: `gcloud docker push gcr.io/project-id/image-name`
3. from VM running docker: `gcloud docker images`
I see nothing and therefore unable to run any containers - do you know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker images` just displays images that have been pulled to the local VM.

Try running `gcloud docker pull gcr.io/project-id/image-name` to get it onto your VM.  Then `docker images` should show it.

If you are on `docker` 1.8 or later (see `docker version`) you can also run: `gcloud docker search gcr.io/project-id` to see the list of images under `project-id`.